# Do the icons flow with this design?

Tags: website-design

I have been working on this website redesign for a customer. I came up with a few ideas and landed on this one. She came back with the response that it's nice, but it's missing something. Maybe it's the icons throwing her off of the design? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to fix the question :) Much better than the original.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think the blue on green doesn't have enough contrast, I'd try using white(-ish) background and green/blue text instead. I also think that the text shadow makes it hard to read, I'd lose them. And I'd probably make the icons bigger and put them on 2 rows or in a slider.

Answer (score 0):

Fonts are the first problem. None of them match/compliment each other, their spacing's and weightings are also wrong.

Next up, colours. Way to heavy handed. Go subtle and stylish.

Spend some time on Pinterest browsing website layouts and designs, make a huge folder of inspiring designs, then sit down and stare at them all for hours. Take notes on what's good, great and horrid.

And, generally speaking, if you don't really, REALLY need icons, just use text.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you're doing it wrong. It's far beyond the problem with the icons.

Here some tips, maybe these would help you:

1. Fix the alignment of the text.
2. Use a proper hierarchy for the text (font size, font color, opacity, font weight even different typeface would help alot)
3. Be consistent on your icon style

Answer (score 0):

Firstly; Change the icons to be a rounded square, similar to the partners box at the bottom. This will immediately look better, following a common structure.

Secondly; Change the colors. Perhaps a white background and change the drill/hunting glyphs to the same color as the green background (make them into negative space icons).

Third; Get rid of the text shadow, and make the font color white, to make the contrast to the background.

Fourth; If you are still unsure, perhaps look at some icon sets already made, since hunting etc might be better with a shotgun, hardware might be a set of tools etc. There are loads of icon sets out there!